# Should we remove the source-code tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently 43 questions tagged [source-code](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/source-code), which to me seems like a totally useless overly generic tag. Should we remove it?

Answer (score 4):

I think we should.

Although some questions really ask about "source code" in a general way, this appears more to be used as a meta tag or a sign of an off-topic question.